# WP_Query orderby meta_value_num ACF Date Picker NOT working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to orderby ACF Date picker custom field, however it is not sorting. I build the query depending on what form inputs are used, but I have tried just hard coding the query as well with no luck. I am submitting this via ajax to display the results on page.

I change order form DESC to ASC and there is no change at all

When I use the similar query via search results the orderby works exactly as expected. I feel like this is a little forrest for the trees.

Here is the code I get when I do a print_r on my query, maybe a fresh set of eyes can help me see a clear solution

```
[query] => Array(
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [s] => 
    [post_type] => 'teamsi-course-dates'
    [meta_query] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [meta_query] => Array(
                [relation] => AND
                [0] => Array(
                    [key] => course_date_start_date
                    [compare] => >=
                    [value] => 20190212
                    [type] => DATE
                )

                [1] => Array(
                    [key] => course_date_start_date
                    [compare] => <=
                    [value] => 20200228
                    [type] => DATE
                )

            )

        )

        [1] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [key] => course_date_start_date
                [value] => 20190212
                [compare] => >
            )

        )

        [relation] => AND
    )

    [tax_query] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [taxonomy] => 'teamsi-program-dept'
            [field] => name
            [terms] => PDMP
        )

    )

    [meta_key] => course_date_start_date,
    ['orderby'] => meta_value_num,
    [order] => ASC
)
```

I am wanting to display by date DESC

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, by adding 'suppress_filters' => true to my $args it allows WP_Query to work with the orderby, you can read more about it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82092/wp-query-orderby-breaks-when-using-ajax

Comment: that made no change to the output, still not sorting by the value in meta_key field